# where to place dynamic nav component code using vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am new in vue. I have a dynamic nav, which look like this:

`<nav>home/news/setting</nav>`

The content in `nav` may change dynamically on different url(I am using vue-router, too). Now, I have a file named Nav.vue. But I don't know where should I use this `Nav.vue` component.Should I use it in `<App/>` or should I write a decorator like `makeNav(element)` and composite it with all my pages?